# Dynamic option values in react form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a component in which i fetch some data. This data has to be displayed in a form as option values part of a select. So the data I fetch will be the options.

The component in which the data will come from is this one :

```
import React from 'react';

import Layout from '../Layout/Layout';
import CmView from './CmView';


export default function CmContainer() {
    someState [/*with items*/]

    return (
        <div>
            <Layout title={'CM Info'}>
                <CmView/>
            </Layout>
        </div>
    )
}
```

And the select is in another component named CmView :

```
import React from 'react'

export default function CmView() {
    return (
        <div>
            <form>
                <select>
                    <option>here comes an item</option>
                </select>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The question is , whats the best way to pass the data down ? Do i loop in the first component or do i pass the data as prop? Im trying to implement the container- view pattern, where the view is only used to display data.

Comment: For the Container/View pattern, you would fetch and maintain state within `CmContainer` and pass down the data to `CmView` where you would `map` the data into the options. https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/react-superpowers-container-pattern-20d664bdae65/

Comment: Thank you @wlh Thats what i was looking for

Comment: No problem. Keep in mind that this type of question will probably be downvoted on this site since it doesn't deal with a programming problem per se. For instance, what did you try and what didn't work? You could either apply the pattern or not and it would work either way. I didn't downvote you, but others will (and already have). If you found the answer you wanted. I suggest deleting this question before it gets downvoted more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the data as an array and loop it in your `CmView` component.

```
import React from 'react';

import Layout from '../Layout/Layout';
import CmView from './CmView';


export default function CmContainer() {
  someState [/*with items*/]

  return (
    <div>
      <Layout title={'CM Info'}>
         <CmView options={options} />
      </Layout>
    </div>
  )
 }
```

And loop in here:

```
import React from 'react'

export default function CmView({ options }) {
    return (
        <div>
            <form>
                <select>
                    {options.map(option => (<option>{option.name}</option>)}
                </select>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```